# multiple condtion in ternary opeartor is not working in tbbuttoncolumn in yii

Tags: php, yii

```
$user_id = 66;
'visible'=>'(($data->message_kind==="ASKED") && 
              (Yii::app()->user>getState("userId")===$user_id))?true:false;'));
```

$user_id is not replacing value 66 ...please help me anyone....

Comment: You just have a string here when you wrap it in quotes.

Comment: What @Rizier123 means is, you have single quote ' if you want to use variables inside string you need to use double quotes ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting this into a string with single quotes ', if you want to use variables inside string you would need to use double quotes ".

However in this case, you do not need to use quotes at all since all you are returning is true or false, so the proper code would be:

```
$user_id = 66;
'visible'=> (($data->message_kind==="ASKED") && 
              (Yii::app()->user>getState("userId")===$user_id))?true:false;));
```